# How to distinguish between android KeyEvent and external device KeyEvent

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, keyevent

I'm reading barcodes/cards with external device connected to android device by USB.

External device sends it's input as KeyEvent to Activity and I can read it in `dispatchKeyEvent()` method inside `Activity` like this

```
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        externalDeviceService.onNewInputFromExternalDevice(((char) event.getUnicodeChar()));
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

But for example when there is focus on some `EditText`, it types external device input to that input field instead of just delegating to service.

Is there a way to distinguish between input from android device(soft keyboard) and from external device(RFID card reader or barcode scanner)?

Obvious solution would be `keyEvent.getDevice().getName()`, and recognize external device to handle event appropriately, but that binds me to specific devices which is huge limitation. Maybe there is a way to check if `KeyEvent` comes from android soft keyboard?

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in the future, I send KeyEvents from `dispatchKeyEvent()` to some outside service, if next character appears in specified amount of time after previous, it means that it comes from scanner/rfid. In other cases I send KeyEvent back to Activity and call `super.dispatchKeyEvent()`

@Edit
Another way is getting list of USB Connected devices from `UsbManager`. Use that list to determine if KeyEvent parent is inside that list to distinguish. Caveat is that, if you connect hardware keyboard, it treats KeyEvents as it comes from Barcode/RFID card Scanner

Comment: can you go into detail on how you did this?  What do you mean after "next character", which method override are you referring to?

Comment: KeyEvents come from `dispatchKeyEvent` inside `Activity`